# Upgraded from Kanna 2.2.1 to 4.0.2 and getting the same error

Tags: swift, kanna

I am rewriting a project I found on Github to learn and teach myself how to use swift and pod files. I upgraded Kanna from 2.2.1 to 4.0.2 because I was getting an arm64 error.

With 4.0.2 I am getting the error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'HTMLDocument'
>
> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

I am unsure about what this error means and how to fix it. It is associated with this if statement:

```
if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: htmlText, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    for itemSize in doc.css("option[value^='']") {
        let itemSizeText = itemSize.text!.lowercased()
                        
        let wishListItemSize = self.websiteInstance!.websiteWishListItem.size!.lowercased()
                        
        if itemSizeText.range(of: wishListItemSize) != nil {
            print("Found size")
                            
            foundItemSize = true
                            
            let itemSizeValue = itemSize["value"]
                            
            self.websiteInstance!.viewController!.websiteBrowser!.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"size-options\").value = \(itemSizeValue!)", completionHandler: nil)
                            
            break
        }
                        
        countSize += 1
    }                    
}
```

Comment: @DávidPásztor If you are going to create a new tag, please do it properly by adding appropriate details to the tag.

Comment: @rmaddy I did add a tag wiki to it, but it needs to go through peer review, since I'm not a 20k user yet

Answer (score 1):

The type signature for the method you are calling is `public func HTML(html: String, url: String? = nil, encoding: String.Encoding, option: ParseOption = kDefaultHtmlParseOption) throws -> HTMLDocument`. The function returns a non-Optional value, but can throw an error.

You can handle the error by either using the `try?` keyword to make the function return `nil` in case an error was thrown and make the optional binding you currently use work like this:

```
if let doc = try? Kanna.HTML(html: htmlText, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {...
```

or rather use `try` and put the function call in a `do-catch` block to see the actual error in case any was thrown.

```
do {
    let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: htmlText, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    for itemSize in doc.css("option[value^='']") {
        let itemSizeText = itemSize.text!.lowercased()

        let wishListItemSize = self.websiteInstance!.websiteWishListItem.size!.lowercased()

        if itemSizeText.range(of: wishListItemSize) != nil {
            print("Found size")
            foundItemSize = true
            let itemSizeValue = itemSize["value"]    
            self.websiteInstance!.viewController!.websiteBrowser!.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"size-options\").value = \(itemSizeValue!)", completionHandler: nil)
            break
        }

        countSize += 1
    }        
} catch {
    print(error)
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: @user2708570 glad I could help. If you found the answer useful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer using the green checkmark symbol next to the answer.